# Changing variable value depending on datetime period

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, variables

Thanks for the clue in the comment below.

Maybe this code will be more specific.

```
import numpy as np 

time_span_one = np.arange('2014-12-22', '2015-12-31', dtype='datetime64[D]')
time_span_two = np.arange('2016-01-01', '2020-01-01', dtype='datetime64[D]')

deadline = np.datetime64('2015-05-01')
payoff_date = np.datetime64('2016-06-01')
total_debt_amount = float(1000)
delta = np.timedelta64(payoff_date - deadline)

for deadline in time_span_one:
    interest = 0.08
for deadline in time_span_two:
    interest = 0.07

interest_amount = (total_debt_amount * delta.astype(float) * interest / 365)
```

I want to calculate "interest_amount" from 2014-12-22 to 2015-12-31 (8%) and from 2016-01-01 to "payoff_date" (7%).

It's simple to do by typing correct pattern in function when I am using only two timestamps but I want to use three different types of percentage and about ten timestamps so it's very important to automate calculations.

Comment: Try to isolate your problem to a few line of codes, a general thumb rule.

Comment: Sorry for that mess before. I am a bit frustrated about stucking in one place for long time.

Comment: I think you want to change your for loop to if statements. Otherwise the interest will always be 0.07.  If deadline in time_span_one:

Answer (score 0):

```
# Change the 'for' loops to 'if' statements
if deadline in time_span_one:
    interest = 0.08
elif deadline in time_span_two:
    interest = 0.07
```

Then you can add as many time spans as you like, and charge different interest rates